# JSON data in listview with images parsing error

Tags: android, json

I am using jsonparser to parse data and images obtained from json response. When i include this code to parse image output is D/AndroidRuntime(441): Shutting down VM 
 D/dalvikvm(441): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries

```
JSONArray attachments = json.getJSONArray(KEY_ATTACHMENTS);
                for(int j = 0; j < attachments.length(); j++){
                    JSONObject d = attachments.getJSONObject(j);
                    JSONObject images = d.getJSONObject(KEY_IMAGES);
                    String thumbnail = d.getString(KEY_THUMB_URL);

                    JSONObject thumnails = d.getJSONObject(KEY_THUMB_URL);
                    String url = author.getString(KEY_URL);
```

Am'i going wrong in parsing the content? can any body help Images are displaying along with data in output. my JSON response is

```
{
"status": "ok",

"posts": [
    {
        "id": 2498,
        "title": "jigsaw lamp imported from thailand",
        "content": "<p>Hi. It&#8217;s a invitation to have a look at a unique lamp shade called jigsaw lamp from thailand. Available in multi attractive colours.</p>\n",
        "date": "2012-12-26 09:48:15",
         "author": {
            "name": "Tapas123456",
                        },
            "attachments": [
            {
                "description": "",
                "caption": "",
                "mime_type": "image/jpeg",
                "images": {

                    "thumbnail": {
                        "url": "http://site/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/646675-50x47.jpg",

                    }
                }
            },...............
```

following is the code

```
     public class CustomizedListView extends Activity {
   JSONArray posts = null;

  // All static variables
  static final String URL = "http://website";



  static final String KEY_POSTS = "posts";
  static final String KEY_ID = "id";
  static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
  static final String KEY_DATE = "date";
  static final String KEY_CONTENT = "content";
  static final String KEY_AUTHOR = "author";
  static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
  static final String KEY_ATTACHMENTS = "attachments";
  static final String KEY_THUMB_URL = "thumbnail";
  static final String KEY_IMAGES = "images";
  static final String KEY_URL = "url";

  ListView list;
     LazyAdapter adapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();


    // Creating JSON Parser instance
            JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

            // getting JSON string from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(URL);
            try {
            posts = json.getJSONArray(KEY_POSTS);
    // looping through all song nodes <song>
            for(int i = 0; i < posts.length(); i++){
                JSONObject c = posts.getJSONObject(i);
                // Storing each json item in variable
                String id = c.getString(KEY_ID);
                String title = c.getString(KEY_TITLE);
                String date = c.getString(KEY_DATE);
                String content = c.getString(KEY_CONTENT);

                // Phone number is agin  JSON Object
                JSONObject author = c.getJSONObject(KEY_AUTHOR);
                String name = author.getString(KEY_NAME);

                JSONArray attachments = json.getJSONArray(KEY_ATTACHMENTS);
                for(int j = 0; j < attachments.length(); j++){
                    JSONObject d = attachments.getJSONObject(j);
                    JSONObject images = d.getJSONObject(KEY_IMAGES);
                    String thumbnail = d.getString(KEY_THUMB_URL);

                    JSONObject thumnails = d.getJSONObject(KEY_THUMB_URL);
                    String url = author.getString(KEY_URL);
                }
        // creating new HashMap
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
        map.put(KEY_ID, id);
        map.put(KEY_TITLE, title);
        map.put(KEY_DATE, date);
        map.put(KEY_NAME, name);
        map.put(KEY_CONTENT, content);

        // adding HashList to ArrayList
        songsList.add(map);
            }   
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

                }


    list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

    // Getting adapter by passing json data ArrayList
    adapter=new LazyAdapter(this, songsList);        
    list.setAdapter(adapter);


    // Click event for single list row
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {


        }
         });        
          } 
            }
```

LazyAdapter.java

```
public class LazyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Activity activity;
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
public ImageLoader imageLoader; 

public LazyAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
    activity = a;
    data=d;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    imageLoader=new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
}

public int getCount() {
    return data.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi=convertView;
    if(convertView==null)
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);

    TextView title = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.title); // title
    TextView date = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.artist); // artist name
    TextView content = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.duration);  // duration
    TextView name = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.name); 
    // duration
    ImageView thumb_image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.list_image); // thumb image

    HashMap<String, String> song = new HashMap<String, String>();
    song = data.get(position);


    ListView list;
    // Setting all values in listview
    title.setText(song.get(CustomizedListView.KEY_TITLE));
    date.setText(song.get(CustomizedListView.KEY_DATE));
    content.setText(song.get(CustomizedListView.KEY_CONTENT));
    name.setText(song.get(CustomizedListView.KEY_NAME));

    imageLoader.DisplayImage(song.get(CustomizedListView.KEY_URL), thumb_image);
    return vi;
        }
        }
```

logcat error
12-29 14:42:59.152: D/AndroidRuntime(449): CheckJNI is ON
12-29 14:42:59.273: D/AndroidRuntime(449): --- registering native functions ---
12-29 14:42:59.732: D/AndroidRuntime(449): Shutting down VM
12-29 14:42:59.742: D/dalvikvm(449): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
12-29 14:42:59.752: I/AndroidRuntime(449): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
12-29 14:43:00.172: D/AndroidRuntime(457): >>>>>>>>>>>>>> AndroidRuntime START <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
12-29 14:43:00.172: D/AndroidRuntime(457): CheckJNI is ON
12-29 14:43:00.292: D/AndroidRuntime(457): --- registering native functions ---
12-29 14:43:00.772: I/ActivityManager(58): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.example.androidhive/.CustomizedListView }
12-29 14:43:00.783: D/AndroidRuntime(457): Shutting down VM
12-29 14:43:00.783: D/dalvikvm(457): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
12-29 14:43:00.792: I/AndroidRuntime(457): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed

Comment: There are maybe interesting error messages before the "Shutting down VM", could you post them?

Comment: posted logcat could you plz look into it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse current json as:

```
   JSONObject json=new JSONObject("pass your json string here");

  JSONArray arrjson = json.getJSONArray("posts");

   for(int j = 0; j < arrjson.length(); j++){
        JSONObject jsonimages = attachments.getJSONObject(j);

       JSONArray attachmentsimages = jsonimages.getJSONArray("attachments");

      for(int i = 0; i < attachmentsimages.length(); i++){

           JSONObject imagesjson = attachmentsimages.getJSONObject(i);

           JSONObject imagesjsonnew = imagesjson.getJSONObject("images");
           JSONObject thumnailsimages = imagesjsonnew.getJSONObject("thumbnail");

           String url = thumnailsimages.getString("url");
     }

}
```

Comment: If i remove this part of code  JSONArray attachments = json.getJSONArray(KEY_ATTACHMENTS);
                for(int j = 0; j < attachments.length(); j++){
                    JSONObject d = attachments.getJSONObject(j);
                    JSONObject images = d.getJSONObject(KEY_IMAGES);
                    String thumbnail = d.getString(KEY_THUMB_URL);

                    JSONObject thumnails = d.getJSONObject(KEY_THUMB_URL);
                    String url = author.getString(KEY_URL);
                } will get data in listview without any image

Comment: @ArunA : means i'm not getting you

Comment: if i comment the above code then i will be able to get listview with data obtained from json response, but i want to add images obtained from json response along with data in listview

Comment: @ArunA : for adding images from web url to ListView you will need to create Custom adapter for ListView and first download image from url as bitmap and then set it as ImageView source

Comment: @ArunA : see this tutorial http://android-er.blogspot.in/2010/06/listview-with-icon-loaded-from-internet.html for getting images from server and then show it in ListView

Comment: @ArunA : and what about http://android-er.blogspot.in/2010/06/listview-with-icon-loaded-from-internet.html link i have provided to u for showing images from server in listview?

Comment: not able to add images in listview i think i am going wrong in parsing the json response emulator is not displaying anything its blank empty screen